# Why is my Socket.io event firing multiple times?

Tags: javascript, socket.io, form-submit

I am building a simple chat room with Socket.io. The user enters a desired username and submits the form.

I check if the username is in use and then fire the `join` event if the username is available, which adds them to the chat, but the `join` events seems to be firing for each user that is currently in the chat - not just once for the new user entering it.

**Client**

```
var socket = io();

// user enters desired username and submits form
$('#chat__join').on('submit', function() {

    // get username value
    var name = $('#chat__name').val();

    // send socket username to check if someone is already using it
    socket.emit('isUserInChat', name);

    return false;
});

// callback for when we know if user is already in chat or not
socket.on('isUserInChat', function(exists, name) {

    if(!exists) {

        // this only fires once per form submission
        console.log('username is available');

        // but this fires per user
        socket.emit("join", name);
    } else {
        // username is taken
        // display error message
    }
});
```

The `socket.emit("join", name);` line seems to fire once when the first person submits the form, which is correct. But then when a second person submits the form, the `join` event is fired twice. When a third person submits the form, it's fired three times. Why is the event firing per user? Shouldn't it only fire per form submission?

**Server**

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    http = require('http').Server(app),
    io = require('socket.io')(http),
    usersObj = {
        users: []
    };

io.on('connection', function(socket) {

    socket.on('isUserInChat', function(username) {

        var flag = false;

        // for each user
        for(var i = 0; i < usersObj.users.length; i++) {

            // if username matches username that was entered
            if(usersObj.users[i].username == username) {

                // set flag to be true
                flag = true;
            }
        }

        // send client true or false
        io.emit('isUserInChat', flag, username);
    });

    socket.on('join', function(name) {

        // construct user
        var user = {
            id: socket.id,
            username: name
        };

        // add user to users object array
        usersObj.users.push(user);

        // send chat message
        io.emit('sendMsg', 'Chat Bot', name+' has connected to the server.');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem confused, but you actually told the event to emit to every client. If you want it to echo only back to the client that's checking the availability

```
io.emit('isUserInChat', flag, username);
```

should be

```
socket.emit('isUserInChat', flag, username);
```

Comment: That is true. When you emit event with 'io' it will emit for all users who are connected to the server.

Comment: Great catch. I'm new to socket.io and didn't notice that. I had copied that line from another function in an example, which emitted the event to everyone. Anyway, making the switch did the trick. Thanks!